If I sell a wash purchase at a subsequent gain, then buy back the same stock does it bring back the loss?
Ok. The question is at the bottom, but all the stuff in between is a necessary read. Sorry for the wordiness, but I need an indisputable answer.
Example. I bought 5000 shares of XYZ at $1.40. I sold them 2 days later at $1.3001 ($499.69 loss.) 3 days later, I buy 9250 at $1.4215 (no wash), and sell at 1.1401 ($2809.97 loss). 9 days later (with no knowledge of wash sales), I buy 5454 shares at $1.10 with an adjusted cost basis of $1.71! My jaw hit the floor. Total loss of $3309.66 to start the day. When I called cust serv, they explained it to me, but not very well. They told me that if I sold at a gain for the Unadjusted Total, then if I rebuy, the wash loss adjustment doesn't come back and the wash is accounted for. I just wouldn't get the write-off back until 30 days after my final sale. I'm fine with that. I don't care.
So, 2 days later, I sold at $1.34 with an Unadjusted Gain of $1308.78, with less of a Total Loss. I wasn't worried. 5 days later, I bought 5486 shares for $2.60. To my horror, the adjusted price was $2.98! New Total loss of $3953.39. After having a minor heart attack, I called customer service again confused, and was told that the last person advised me wrong, so the total loss came back, plus some. I was in tears. So now I'm white-knuckling until I can sell when the price goes above $2.98.
Finally, the real question is, if I sell at a Total gain, does that mean that if I repurchase the stock within 30 days, the wash won't come back to bite me again? I sure hope not. This stock has serious promise of breaking out, and I don't want to miss it when it does.

Wash sales is a term in tax law, so you need to tell us what jurisdiction you're in - different countries handle wash sales differently. In any case, if the stock has a serious prospect, why do you care about adjustments to the basis?

In the US, if you dispose of all the shares during the tax year, and don't repurchase within 30 days, all the wash sales are netted out and you can essentially ignore them.

(Assuming US wash sale rules)
Yes, if you sell at a loss and re-buy within 30 days, the loss is added to the cost basis of the stock you bought for tax purposes.  This is so that the tax benefit of the loss is deferred until you close out your position and do not buy back within 30 days.  It's to prevent tax loss harvesting where you sell at a loss near the end of the tax year to get a deduction, but buy back the stock soon after (or before).
So far, you have a total net realized loss of $3,100 that is applied to the re-bought position.
If this all happened recently (i.e. December, 2024) then it just means you cannot claim a loss this year if you buy again within 30 days. If you want to re-buy, then you can claim a loss (if you still have one) on next year's taxes.

So now I'm white-knuckling until I can sell when the price goes above $2.98.

Well that would have been your overall break-even point anyway without the wash sale rule. The difference is only whether you can claim the realized loss on this years taxes or later.

if I sell at a Total gain, does that mean that if I repurchase the stock within 30 days, the wash won't come back to bite me again?

Yes, if you have a total net gain then there is no loss to trigger the wash sale rules.  There are no tax laws (in the US at least) that defer tax gain harvesting.

This stock has serious promise of breaking out, and I don't want to miss it when it does.

Then why have you been selling it at a loss?

In the US wash sale rules are specifically to prevent short term tax loss harvesting, while long term tax gain recognition. In other countries where there's no preferential treatment over tax periods wash sales may not even be a thing, or behave differently to prevent different types of abuse.

Sorry. This answer wasn't aimed at you.  I couldn't figure out how to reply to the person who asked me that quotation l question.       *I sold it at a loss because I was new and I panicked. I know not to do that any more. I'm holding on until there is profit.

@littleadv Also changes in tax situations. If you're in a high tax bracket this year, but you're retiring and your rate will go down next year, realizing the loss would have more benefit this year.

@LeahH wash sale doesn't change the end result, it just defers the tax benefit to later to potentially offset it with the tax penalty. Bottom line, with wash sale adjustment or without it, you get the same value - which is exactly the point of wash sale rules. They're intended to prevent you from trying to time the market for tax purposes.
